# Python PynamoDB - Creating dynamic queries with Flask

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am using PynamoDB and trying to genrate a dynamic query/scan on attributes from a flask request.  Assuming the following model:

```
class Test(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = "test"
        region = "us-west-2"
    a = NumberAttribute(hash_key=True)
    b = NumberAttribute(range_key=True)
    c = UnicodeAttribute()
```

I have this bolted to Flask, so that when a user sends a request with query arguments such as `?a=123&b=456` I can turn this into a filter within PynamoDB to return results which match records with those two filters.

The following works for a single attribute:

```
>>> query = operator.eq(Test.a, 123)
>>> list(Test.scan(query))
[Test<4426599961>]
```

I am looking to be able to bolt this onto a dynamic number of attributes (beyond a,b and c for example)

I tried turning this into a tuple, but that seems to break with the following error:

```
>>> query = (operator.eq(Test.a, 123), operator.eq(Test.b, 456))
>>> list(Test.scan(*query))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Invalid type for parameter Segment, value: b = {'N': '1'}, type: <class 'pynamodb.expressions.condition.Comparison'>, valid types: <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>
```

Any ideas on how I can construct a dynamic filter to pass into the PynamoDB scan method?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
q = { 'a': 123, 'b': 456 }

query = None
for fieldname in q:
    field = getattr(Test, fieldname, None)
    if field is None: continue
    clause = field == q[fieldname]
    query = clause if query is None else query & clause

print(list(Test.scan(cond)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
query = (Test.a == 123) | (Test.b == 456)
list( Test.scan(query))
```